# Adding page numbers in html print-view

Tags: html

I am printing an HTML div with repeatable headers and footers. The repeatable headers and footers have been generated using an HTML table's thead and tfoot elements. Now, there is a requirement to generate page nos. after the footer on each page. I have done some searching on the net and found a few suggestions. But none of the suggestions gives the correct solution.

I have tried using the following CSS code to generate the nos.:

```
tfoot:after {
    counter-increment: page;
    content: counter(page);
}
```

But this code generates 1 as the page number for all pages on chrome. Also, only on the first page, is the page number gets printed after the footer. On other pages on chrome, page numbers are printed before the footer.

On firefox, the first page gets 2 as the page number, while other pages don't get any page nos.

Does anyone know of any way to generate the page nos. using CSS?

Answer (score 0):

Bro it doesn't need CSS , please tell that the solution is working or not

```
<h1> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed erat diam, feugiat non quam quis, lobortis tincidunt sapien. Praesent neque tortor, sagittis nec tristique at, elementum non arcu. Phasellus tempor ac dui at egestas. Nam tellus eros, malesuada nec lectus non, condimentum ullamcorper sapien. Vestibulum vel fermentum nulla, at sollicitudin orci. Etiam rhoncus, sem pharetra auctor ultrices, turpis odio suscipit risus, at blandit metus turpis in eros. Vestibulum molestie, magna at porttitor dapibus, mi sapien maximus mi, non elementum risus purus eu velit. Aenean luctus metus porttitor consequat mattis. Ut vel nibh eget nisi sagittis porttitor. </h1>
<center>
<footer>
<h2> 1 </h2>
</footer>
</center>
```

By doing this the page no will automatically go into the footer just replace 1 to your page numbers. Thanks!

Comment: It wont work. The pages would be dynamically generated by the browser. There is no option for me to manually set the page nos.